# IPFS add not working

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, ipfs

I am working on a dapp and wish to upload a file on ipfs and retrieve its hash to be used further.
The concerned code is as follows

```
const ipfsClient = require(‘ipfs-http-client’)

const ipfs = ipfsClient({ host: ‘ipfs.infura.io’, port: 5001, protocol: ‘https’ })

captureFile = event => {

    event.preventDefault()

    const file = event.target.files[0]

    const reader = new window.FileReader()

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)

    

    reader.onloadend = () => {

      this.setState({ buffer: Buffer(reader.result) })

      console.log('buffer', this.state.buffer)

    }
}

uploadAsset = (cost) => {

console.log("Submitting file to ipfs...")

ipfs.add( this.state.buffer, (error, result) => { //Execution stops here

  console.log('Ipfs result', result)

  if(error) {

    console.log("Error")  

    console.error(error)

    return

  }

console.log("no error")  

  this.setState({ loading: true })

  this.state.dstock.methods.uploadAsset(result[0].hash, cost).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {

    this.setState({ loading: false })

  })

})
```

The output is as given below. The code isn't returning the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this response might be a bit late but until just a moment ago I was experiencing the same problem as you. However, I managed to find a solution! Even if you've also managed to get this to work, I'll share how I fixed this for posterity.

The reason `ipfs.add` seems to just not work is that it needs to be part of an `async/await` function. If it isn't, it just seems not to execute. Here's what my code is like; it's not identical to yours but it's pretty similar and should hopefully give you a good idea of how this should work.

```
const [ipfsHash, setIpfsHash] = useState("");
const [isFile, setFile] = useState(null);
const [buffer, setBuffer] = useState(null);

const captureFile = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files[0]) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setFile(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
        
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0])
        reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                setBuffer(reader.result)
        })
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (buffer) {
        getHash()
    }
});

async function getHash() {
    
    try {
        const uploadResult = await ipfs.add(Buffer.from(buffer))
        setIpfsHash(uploadResult.path)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
        toast.error(e.message)
        return
    }
}
```

I hope this helps! I feel like this should be better documented.